# Change the LabelTemplate on an Infragistics XamDoughnutChart

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

I have an Infragistics WPF `XamDoughnutChart` which displays data binded from an `ObservableCollection` called `Data` and shows `Data.Value` and `Data.Label` on its chart labels.

```
<Grid>
    <ig:XamDoughnutChart x:Name="MyDonut" 
                         CenterData="{Binding TotalItemCount}">
        <ig:XamDoughnutChart.Series>
            <ig:RingSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                           ValueMemberPath="Value" 
                           LabelMemberPath="Label">
            </ig:RingSeries>
        </ig:XamDoughnutChart.Series>
    </ig:XamDoughnutChart>
</Grid>
```

I am trying to change the `LabelTemplate` as mentioned here: https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/16.2/infragisticswpf.controls.charts.xamdatachart~infragistics.controls.charts.hierarchicalringseries_members

But nothing I try works.  Here is my new XAML with all my attempts:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyLabelTemplate">
        <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="test"/>                 <-- **This shows 'test' in blue
        <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="{Binding}"/>            <-- Does nothing
        <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="{Binding Path=Label}"/> <-- Does nothing
        <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/> <-- Does nothing
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ig:XamDoughnutChart x:Name="MyDonut" 
                         CenterData="{Binding TotalCount}">
        <ig:XamDoughnutChart.Series>
            <ig:RingSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                           ValueMemberPath="Value" 
                           LabelMemberPath="Label"
                           LabelTemplate="{StaticResource MyLabelTemplate}">  <-- **Add a LabelTemplate**
            </ig:RingSeries>
        </ig:XamDoughnutChart.Series>
    </ig:XamDoughnutChart>
</Grid>
```

How can I actually change this labels template?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
<ig:RingSeries.LabelTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Label}" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ig:RingSeries.LabelTemplate>
```